# Change Multiple Classes with the same name using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Check out my small project on codepen below...

http://codepen.io/ajduff14/pen/DlHge

Basically I'm just testing out my JavaScript knowledge and I want to learn how to change all the buttons to the same class and use JavaScript to input a color that will change the background color of all the buttons with the given class "buttons". I can only manage to get it to work for 1 class at a time but not several.

It's probably a simple answer but I've done quite a bit of digging for it already and I can't find one! Could someone please help?

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some trivial mistakes in your HTML and JS code.

1) In many places, instead of class="buttons" for input tag, you specified it as id="buttons". Remember that you should have a unique id for each element.

2) You were setting the style.backgroundColor property for buttons[3] and not for all objects with class name buttons.

document.getElementsByClassName('buttons') gets you an array of objects with class name "buttons." You need to iterate over every element of this array and set its background color property to appropriate value.

You could use a for-in loop or a standard for loop to achieve this purpose. I have used the for-in loop.

```
for (button in buttons) {
    buttons[button].style.backgroundColor = div2.children[0].value;
}
```

See this link for a working copy of your project: http://jsfiddle.net/mayank_agarwal/LaQuz/

Comment: Thanks for this, I noticed about the 2 points you made, I did those purposely just testing to see how the code reacted and I didn't change all the id's until i could do it on a few classes first! I'm not 100% familiar with the for or in loops but I'll have a good read at them to understand how it reacts with my code, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change classes or styles on many elements at the same time, you'll have to iterate and apply it to one element at a time

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons');

for (var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {

    buttons[i].style.background = 'red';
    buttons[i].className = buttons[i].className + ' newclass';

}
```

Comment: "There is no way to change classes or styles on many elements at the same time" Not true, there is a way to edit the class itself (with `document.styleSheets`), but the API isn't really easy to use, so it's probably not adapted for what he needs.

Comment: @sebcap26 - Uhm, that would be like inserting a style tag etc. it doesn't change the element at all, and then we're talking about CSS, and it should be obvious that there is a way to apply styles to multiple elements with the same class.